# Permission issue using remote development extension to attach to a docker image

Tags: docker

I have added current user to docker group and I'm able to run docker commands like `docker run hello-world` in terminal opened in vscode with no problem, but vscode doesn't let me attach to a running container, giving "current user does not have permission to run docker. Try adding the user to the 'docker' group" error message. 
My system is Ubuntu 18.04, VS code is 1.39.0-insider

Answer (score 24):

If you've not already created a docker group

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Then

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Then log out and back in (or reboot) again.

Comment: a reboot was required for me after these steps on ubuntu

Comment: Running `newgrp docker` should activate the change without a reboot.

Answer (score 12):

Had the same issue. The reason for the problem was that the vscode server was still running with the old user privileges (without the docker group). Kill the respective process on the remote machine, then reload your vscode windows and everything should work without a reboot.

```
$ ps aux|grep bin/code-server # find out process id
$ kill <process id>
```